# App crashes while re-opening map in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-flutter

while opening map screen from any different screen time it crashes with the null array error, and also gets preferred renderer null. Here are the logs of the crash.

D/MapsInitializer( 3326): preferredRenderer: null

> D/zzcb    ( 3326): preferredRenderer: null

I/Google Maps Android API( 3326): Google Play services package version: 230914044

I/Google Maps Android API( 3326): Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203115000

I/PlatformViewsController( 3326): Using hybrid composition for platform view: 2

E/AndroidRuntime( 3326): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 255

E/AndroidRuntime( 3326): Process: com.zone.app, PID: 3326

**E/AndroidRuntime( 3326): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get
length of null array**

E/AndroidRuntime( 3326):    at java.nio.ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.put(ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.java:122)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3326):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.n.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230914044@23.09.14 (190400-0):2)

**E/AndroidRuntime( 3326):  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.n.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230914044@23.09.14 (190400-0):3)**

E/AndroidRuntime( 3326):    at
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.d.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230914044@23.09.14 (190400-0):2)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3326):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.ao.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230914044@23.09.14 (190400-0):12)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3326):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bx.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230914044@23.09.14 (190400-0):29)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3326):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bq.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230914044@23.09.14 (190400-0):151)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3326):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.at.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230914044@23.09.14 (190400-0):48)
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter( 3326): Compat change id reported: 194532703; UID 10278; state: ENABLED

I/TRuntime.CctTransportBackend( 3326): Making request to: https://crashlyticsreports-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog

D/TrafficStats( 3326): tagSocket(120) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1

I/TRuntime.CctTransportBackend( 3326): Status Code: 200

D/FlutterGeolocator( 3326): Detaching Geolocator from activity

D/FlutterGeolocator( 3326): Flutter engine disconnected. Connected engine count 0

D/FlutterGeolocator( 3326): Disposing Geolocator services

E/FlutterGeolocator( 3326): Geolocator position updates stopped

D/FlutterGeolocator( 3326): Stopping location service.

D/FlutterGeolocator( 3326): Unbinding from location service.

D/FlutterGeolocator( 3326): Destroying location service.

D/FlutterGeolocator( 3326): Stopping location service.

D/FlutterGeolocator( 3326): Destroyed location service.
Lost connection to device.

Expecting a crash-free working map.
I tried to find out which array getting null but, unfortunately all the things are working fine still map crashes after opening more than one time.

Comment: Please edit the error log and show it as `log` instead. And please, paste in your map screen as well. If you notice any pattern that leads to the crash, for example, only crash from sreen A to screen map, then please paste them as well.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too. So what I did was preserve the map state even after the dispose of screen.

Comment: Can you add a link on how to do this ? Some explanation wound help begginers to achieve this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).